# How to know if it's a 2-node or 3-node in a 2-3 tree?

Tags: c++, tree, 2-3-tree

I have a binary search tree, and I created a struct for the node that represents one element and the child to its left, yet, I cannot figure out the mechanism on how to check if it's a 2 node, with one element and two children or if it's 3 node, with two elements and three children. Would someone please give me a hint ?

This is my template class for the BNode

```
template<class E>
class BNode
{
    public:
        struct Entry
        {
            E value;
            BNode* left;
        };
        bool IsThree();

    private:
        bool _three;
        Entry _first, _second;
        BNode* _right;
};

template<class E>
bool BNode<E>::IsThree()
{
// 

}
```

Comment: A binary search tree with three children per node?

Comment: from my understanding, it's a 2-3 trees

Comment: Obviously (?) you need to check whether you have 2 or 3 non-NULL BNode pointers. I.e. check _first.left, _second.left and _right.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I looked it up, and I can't put in a new tag 2-3 tree in there unless I have at least 1500 reputations :(

Comment: What is `bool _three;`? Seems to me like it's supposed to indicate three children, no?

Comment: @john: but the 3-node can have only 2 children. It is not required to have all 3 children

Comment: @interjay: I variable _three is there to hold the return valued of the bool IsThree(). That way, you would know if that node has one element or two elements.

Comment: @HoangMinh Well, yes. If it has only two children then set one of the three pointers to NULL. That's the test. Do you understand pointers? Do you know what NULL is? It seems completely obvious that this is what you need to do.

Comment: @john: thanks, I got it now